# How to update state in App.js upon completion of store rehydration?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-persist

I have a pretty standard boilerplate. Basically I implemented Redux-persist and render loading screen till the store been rehydrated.

> Store.js

```
const store = Reactotron.createStore(
  reducers,
  undefined,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk),
    offline({
      ...offlineConfig,
      persistCallback: () => Reactotron.log('HEY LOADED') //<<====How to update rehydrated state in App.js
    })
  )
);
```

> App.js

```
import store from './Store';

export default class App extends Component {
  state = { rehydrated: false };

  ...

  render() {
    if (!this.state.rehydrated) return <Loading />

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <MainNavigator />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
```

Based on the above setup, I can see logging after store rehydrated successfully. But I'm wondering how it can update the state of App.js?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `PersistGate` to show loading screen until your persisted state has been retrieved. As explained on the second part here, https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#basic-usage